# What is the meaning of the Schwarzschild coordinate $t$ in the Schwarzschild vacuum solution inside the event horizon?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, coordinate-systems, time, event-horizon

According to the current interpretation of the Schwarzschild **vacuum** solution inside the event horizon, the Schwarzschild coordinate $r$, while becoming "*the* time coordinate (...) also retains its geometrical significance" (Rindler, "Relativity: special, general and cosmological", p.261, Rindler's emphasis).

Now, with $r$ in this double role, what is $t$ supposed to represent? It cannot represent time, because time is already represented by $r$; and it cannot represent any spatial degree of freedom, because these are exhausted by $r$, and by the two angular Schwarzschild coordinates.

See Box 7 in Chapter 7 of Taylor, Wheeler, Bertschinger, "Exploring Black Holes", 2nd edition, and don't forget to notice the Figure inside that Box. The authors really believe that inside the event horizon the r coordinate keeps measuring some sort of "distance to the origin".

Comment: Can you write the metric in the coordinates you're talking about?

Answer (score 3):

$r$ is just a time coordinate inside the event horizon. $t,θ,\phi$ are the spatial coordinates.

I assume what Rindler means by "retains its geometrical significance" is that the 3D surface at fixed $r$ is geometrically a cylinder of infinite length, whose cross sections are spheres of radius $r$, both inside and outside the horizon. But outside the horizon the metric signature on the cylinder is $-{+}+$ (it's the world-sheet of a sphere), while inside the horizon the signature is $+{+}+$ (it's a Euclidean cylinder, the cross-sectional radius of which decreases at later times (that is, smaller $r$), and goes to $0$ at the singularity).

Comment: @FernandoPassos Topology of space alone is not well defined, because what is space and what is time may be different in different coordinate systems. If you are in a moving train, are you really moving in space or only in time? It depends on whom you ask. The Schwarzschild solution is a solution of the equation $R=0$ with the Ricci tensor, not Einstein tensor. The Ricci tensor describes vacuum with no matter. There is no point particle in the Schwarzschild solution, only vacuum. The mass of a black hole is not the mass of some particle at the origin, but the energy of the gravitational field.

Comment: When we derive the Schwarzschild soln, we also have the fact that $dr$ is the radial distance as measured by the far away observer. If $r$ is to become timelike suddenly at one point then how are you to reconcile the fact that $dr$ should measure a spacelike distance as measured by the far away observer. Alternatively if $r$ represents the reduced area coordinate ( such that area of 3 spheres is $4*\pi*r^2$), then inside the horizon the area of 3 spheres is given by $4\pi r^2$ but now $r$ is timelike then what does it say about the area of spheres. Does it mean that at constant $t$  (cont)

Comment: Which is spacelike now the area of each sphere decreases

Answer (score 3):

> inside the event horizon, the Schwarzschild coordinate , while becoming "the time coordinate (...) also retains its geometrical significance"

This is correct. But, …

> the r coordinate keeps measuring some sort of "distance to the origin".

This is not.

The geometrical significance of the Schearzschild $r$ coordinate never was as “some sort of distance to the origin”. The geometrical significance is that for constant $t$ and $r$ the surface defined by $\theta$ and $\phi$ is a 2 sphere with area $4\pi r^2$. This geometrical significance is retained inside the horizon, and allows us to easily write the $\theta$ and $\phi$ terms of the metric, even inside the horizon.

> what is  supposed to represent? It cannot represent time, because time is already represented by ; and it cannot represent any spatial degree of freedom, because these are exhausted by , and by the two angular Schwarzschild coordinates.

$t$ is indeed a spatial degree of freedom. Locally, inside the horizon you can form a tetrad with a clock and three orthogonal rulers. The tetrad can be aligned and scaled so that locally one of the rulers indicates the Schwarzschild $t$ and the clock represents the Schwarzschild $r$. Forces can be applied in the $t$ direction and in all local respects it is indeed a spatial direction.

Again, the geometrical significance that $r$ retains is not as a distance to the origin nor as a spatial degree of freedom. It is simply the relationship to the surface area of the $\theta$, $\phi$ spheres.

Comment: When we derive the Schwarzschild soln, we also have the fact that $dr$ is the radial distance as measured by the far away observer. If $r$ is to become timelike suddenly at one point then how are you to reconcile the fact that $dr$ should measure a spacelike distance as measured by the far away observer. Alternatively if $r$ represents the reduced area coordinate ( such that area of 3 spheres is $4*\pi*r^2$), then inside the horizon the area of 3 spheres is given by $4\pi r^2$ but now $r$ is timelike then what does it say about the area of spheres. Does it mean that at constant $t$  (cont)

Comment: Which is spacelike now the area of each sphere decreases. That is you a sphere centred at some distance from the black hole inside the horizon. And as time progresses forward (which means as r goes to 0 and r is timelike) the area of each sphere decreases while $t$ which is spacelike determines the position of the center of the sphere. Thus the area of each sphere inside the horizon decreases with time. Does the $r$ coordinate means that inside the horizon.

Comment: @Shashaank said “When we derive the Schwarzschild soln, we also have the fact that  is the radial distance as measured by the far away observer.” I have never seen any derivation that does that. I would be quite skeptical of any such derivation. For a good derivation see this https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9712019

Comment: Ok but what about the interpretation of $r$ as depicting the area of $2$ sphere inside the horizon as I have continued the comments ( after alternatively)

Comment: Does the radius of the 2 sphere decrease inside the horizon with time  at all

Comment: A distant observer cannot measure anything inside the event horizon @Shashaank

Comment: @ProfRob yes, I understand that. But what I am asking is that whether the area of  a 2 sphere (centred inside the horizon) decrease with time (i.e decrease with decreasing r) or is tha5 interpretation also incorrect

Comment: @Shashaank sorry, I thought that I had responded already, but I must have deleted it or something. As proper time increases along some timelike object’s worldline, r decreases, and so does the area of the 2 sphere on which the object momentarily resides

Comment: @Dale ok I got it. So the area of every 2 sphere decreases inside the horizon. Good. But one thing. The formula $4\pi*r^2$ giving the area makes any sense when $r$ is a spacelike coordinate. If $r$ is a timelike coordinate, I can mentally change variables $r\rightarrow t$ and vice-versa. Now the formula reads $4\pi*t^2$ with $t$ as timelike. Does this give an area. To get area (which is spacelike thing you need to have something spacelike in your formula for the area). What sense does the formula even make when you have a timelike coordinate there in place of $r$... does it even given area....

Comment: @Shashaank in standard GR time is measured in the same units as distance and even if you consider different units they are still considered to have the same dimension.

Comment: @Dale ahhh, yes right got it...